# How do I add an output file to the result window using mstest?

Tags: c#, mstest

My test has a file as output.  I would like to see that file in the output window for my test (i.e. if I right click on a completed test and select: View Test Results Details).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your TestClass has a property called TestContext of type TestContext then inside your test you can add the line:

```
TestContext.AddResultFile(fullyQualifiedName);
```

where the fullyQualifiedName is a string of the path to your file.